# "Got Notifications" vs. "Received Notifications"

Tags: phrases

For some reason the phrase "Got Notifications" seems rough. "Received Notifications" sounds a bit more natural.

Is there something wrong with the phrase "Got Notifications"? Is there a principle behind this that can explain why I get a funny feeling about it?

Comment: _Get_ is informal for _receive_, while _notifications_ is formal for _news_. They should be both informal or both formal; mashups don't work so well.

Comment: That explains it :)

Comment: John I'd upvote that if it was an answer.

Comment: @JohnLawler I wouldn't have read "notifications" as meaning "news": I would have understood it as notification(s) (notice) that something has happened, e.g. that we can go ahead with the project, that the money has been received, that the e-mail(s) have been read, ... . Hence, I would go with "received notifications". (I also wouldn't have capitalised "notifications" - I know you didn't: the questioner did.)

Answer (score 2):

'Get' is informal for 'receive', while 'notifications' is formal for 'news'.

It is incongruous to use words of different formality. It would sound better if they were both informal or both formal; mashups don't work so well.